# change div content by clicking an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div:

```
<div class="main_mark">
    <img src="/assets/welcome_main.png" alt="main" class="main_mark_image" />
</div>
```

I want the next thing: when the user click the image, this div will changed to:

```
<div class="main_mark">
    <embed width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XjR-4lbK1mI" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    </embed>
</div>
```

so in my javascript, I have tried to do something like:

```
$(".main_mark_image").click(function () {
    $("#main_mark").innerHTML = "<embed width=420 height=345 src=http://www.youtube.com/v/XjR-4lbK1mI type=application/x-shockwave-flash></embed>";
});
```

but it doesn't change anything..

any help aapreciated!

Comment: No part of your question involves Ruby or Rails, you should only tag your question with relavent technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html` function : http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$(".main_mark_image").click(function () {
    $("#main_mark").html("<embed width=420 height=345 src=http://www.youtube.com/v/XjR-4lbK1mI type=application/x-shockwave-flash></embed>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".main_mark").html("Your code")`instead of `$("#main_mark").innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

main_mark is a class not a id.  Use .main_mark

Answer (score 1):

use a combo of both @sdespont and @kmd97

```
$(".main_mark_image").click(function () {
// Changed selector to class
$(".main_mark").html("<embed width=420 height=345 src=http://www.youtube.com/v/XjR-4lbK1mI     type=application/x-shockwave-flash></embed>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".main_mark_image").click(function () {

    $(".main_mark").html = "<embed width=420 height=345 src=http://www.youtube.com/v/XjR-4lbK1mI     type=application/x-shockwave-flash></embed>";
    });
```